# Django - saving onetonone linked forms at same time not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I've have the following forms:

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

class UserDetailForm (forms.ModelForm):
    linked_user = forms.CharField (required = True)
    linked_password = forms.CharField (required = True, widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    connections = forms.IntegerField (required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User_detail
        fields = ('linked_user','linked_password','connections')
```

I'm trying to save them at the same time if both valid using:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        linked_form = UserDetailForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if all((form.is_valid(),linked_form.is_valid())):
            user = form.save()
            linked = linked_form.save(commit=False)
            linked.user = user
            linked.save()
            msg = "Profile Updated"
        else:
            return error(request)
```

This is the User_detail model:

```
class User_detail (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField (
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
        )
    linked_user = models.CharField (
        verbose_name = 'LinkedIn Username',
        max_length = 50,
    )
    linked_password  = models.CharField (
        max_length = 50,                                
        verbose_name = 'LinkedIn Password',
    )
    connections = models.IntegerField (
        verbose_name = 'Connections per day',
        default = 24,
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name)
```

The first form is being saved, the second isn't and I don't understand what I'm missing

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error being given? If so, could you post it?

Comment: There is no error.  It comes back saying it has been saved.  The first form updates (`user=form.save()`); the second (linked_form) doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `linked_form = UserDetailForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`. `request.user` is not an instance of model `User_detail`.

What is happening is that, django is trying to find the instance in the model and not finding any. You need to provide a valid `User_detail` instance so that django can update that instance.

Reference: [save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)